# Salesforce stackexchange reputation issue

Tags: discussion

I have an account in salesforce stackexchange with 629 reputation , suddenly i got with 329 reputation and user account is removed from my stack exchange

it is showing:

-25 serial voting was reversed

-250 user has removed

I want to recover the account  how? please anyone guide me for this solution,I am really getting depressed, **why my account is removed**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few suspicious rings of users who have been voting heavily for each other, and they have been logging in from the same IP ranges. In addition, the email address you provided in the comments corresponds to more than one of the users involved, including the one user in that voting ring which has not been deleted. You should have just gotten an email for *that* account.

This behavior is often referred to as "**[sock puppetry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)**" with one person having a "puppet master" account and several "sock puppet" accounts that they use to artificially inflate their reputation. While that may not be what you were doing, the evidence strongly suggests one person was running at least five distinct accounts on this exchange, and another (possibly separate) person was running another three.

**Please limit your involvement with the Stack Exchange to one account.** If you would like to appeal the changes that were made, please use the [Contact Us](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) link and state your case. Merging separate user accounts is messy, and I believe it requires a Stack Exchange employee to assist.

Answer (score 4):

## serial voting was reversed

This means that a user visited a bunch of your questions/answers in a row, and the system flagged it as a serial voting. This is to prevent voting spam, such as one user discovering another user's questions/answers and deciding to upvote/downvote many values at once. This might be a collaboration (lots of upvotes) or revenge (lots of downvotes). Generally, there was no change in your reputation; it was simply added then removed (i.e. there is a corresponding +25 that counters the -25).

## user was removed

This message means that a user was deleted, either at their request or because it was a spammer, so all of their votes have been removed. Again, this is perfectly normal, and simply means the 250 points that user contributed to you was reversed (i.e. there was a +250 elsewhere in your history from this user).

It's a bit disconcerting at first (I've had it happen a few times), but it's not a reflection on your contributions to the community, but simply the system working as intended to keep reputation fair. As you continue to interact with the community, your reputation will naturally rise as you ask good questions, give good answers, and accept answers.

---

Further reading:

- [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829)
- [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470)

Comment: it is not possible to recover my old account@sfdcfox

Comment: @Learninguser One of our moderators can assist you with recovering or merging your accounts.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Could you help this user?

Comment: please sfdcfox first time i am facing this issue , help me and told what i have done mistakes before,I want old account

Comment: @Learninguser: Please use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to request your other be account merged into the one you are using now. None of the other users of the site, including moderators, can help. You have to use the contact form.